# Como impedir que uma regra CSS do BODY seja refletida em um determinado Elemento contido nele?

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal

Estou criando um modal em uma página, e como de costume quero que quando o modal esteja sendo renderizado, a tela que está "por baixo" dele fica desfocada, escura. Eu tenho uma classe que representa o meu modal, e nela o atributo _conteiner contém exatamente o elemento HTML que é renderizado como modal e eu fiz o seguinte ajeito para tentar colocar o efeito de foco no modal:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu diminui o brilho do body, e tentei aumentar apenas o brilho do modal, porém o modal fica escura porque o estilo do body sobrepõe o dele. Gostaria de saber se é possível ignorar a herança para essa propriedade, ou forçar que o valor usado na propriedade (algo semelhante ao !important nos arquivos CSS) seja o que eu definir.

Comment: Use uma div com position fixed que fique oculta logo antes de fechar o body, e quando o modal abrir coloque os estilos nela, e não diretamente no body

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível, pois os elementos filhos fazer parte dele.

A solução é usar uma backlayer no modal, que também vai te permitir fechar o modal ao clicar nela.

Exemplo:

```js
var openModalBtn = document.querySelector("#open-modal");
var modalBacklayer = document.querySelector("#modal-backlayer");
var modal = document.querySelector("#modal");

function openModal() {
  modal.classList.add('active');
}

function closeModal() {
  modal.classList.remove('active');
}

openModalBtn.addEventListener('click', () => { openModal() });
modalBacklayer.addEventListener('click', () => { closeModal() });
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none; /* escondido até ter a classe "active" */
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index 100; /* pode ser maior, dependendo do seu site. */
  padding: 15px;
}

.modal.active {
  display: flex;
}

.modal-backlayer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.8;  
  z-index: 1; /* dentro do modal, atras do conteúdo */
}

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2; /* na frente do backlayer */
  background-color: white;
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Body Content</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec lacus dui, suscipit sed purus nec, tempus pulvinar leo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
<button id="open-modal">Open modal</button>


<div class="modal active" id="modal">
  <div class="modal-backlayer" id="modal-backlayer"></div>
  
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h1>Modal Content</h1>
    <p>Morbi efficitur dignissim finibus. Morbi laoreet risus auctor, aliquam neque quis, cursus turpis. Ut in fringilla quam, nec ullamcorper erat. Nam vulputate ex non sapien maximus, nec accumsan nulla lacinia.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```